# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'naturalWidth' of null - FabricJs - preview a video in Fabric.js via loadFromJSON

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html5-video, fabricjs

There is one issue I am facing while trying to preview video on a fabric.js canvas.

**FabricJS Version Tried: 4.0.0-beta.8 And 3.6.3 same error in both**

It gives error saying

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'naturalWidth' of null                          :fabric.js:20490
```

Code for how I am adding video to canvas:

```
let objects = slideData.getObjects();
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    if (objects[i].hasOwnProperty('videoUrl')) {
        var videoElement = createVideoElement(objects[i]['videoUrl']); //this function returns a video element
        var video = new fabric.Image(videoElement, {left: objects[i]['left'], top: objects[i]['top'], isBackgroundVideo: true});
        slideData.add(video);//adding video to canvas.
        video.sendBackwards();//setting video to be on the back so I can show text in front of it
        console.log(slideData);
    }
}
```

Code for how I am trying to preview video on canvas:

```
let jsonData = JSON.stringify(slideData.toObject(propertiesToSave)); //this is an array of properties which we want to save which includes isBackgroundVideo: true
slideData.loadFromJSON(jsonData, slideData.renderAll.bind(slideData), function(o, object) { //loading saved canvas data from JSON
    object.set('selectable', false);
    object.set('cursorHover', 'default');
    let objects = slideData.getObjects();
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        if (objects[i].hasOwnProperty('isBackgroundVideo')) {
            objects[i].getElement().play();
            fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(function render() {
                slideData.renderAll();
                fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(render);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

But when i execute this code then fabric.js gives error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'naturalWidth' of null                          :fabric.js:20490
```

I tried most solutions but it just does not work. I am not sure what is wrong here. If I am doing something wrong or this is just a bug in fabric.js

If you guys need more code then I can provide just comment what you need. Thanks

Comment: this question can be improved if you add the following information:
1. fabric.js version
2. full stack traces (not just error messages)
3. show a piece of code where you call `slideData.dispose()` (in my answer I assume you do this)

Comment: Thanks for your time to assess the question and tell how it can be improved. I have added the versions which I faced problem with. But I don't have stack traces because this question is 5months old and I am not working on that project anymore. Also in my code I never used `slideData.dispose()` so there was something wrong in the code which I attached. Your answer is informational but sorry I can't accept it as correct answer because I don't want other people to get the idea that my problem was solved with your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pay atention to the statement `slideData.renderAll.bind(slideData)`.

Is it possible that you dispose `slideData` canvas somewhere else in your code?

After the disposal `slideData.contextContainer` becomes `null`.

And there's a reference to `slideData.contextContainer.naturalWidth` inside some internal fabric.js function (I don't know exactly, you can find function name in the error stack trace in web console. let's assume `slideData.renderAll`). It explains why do you get `Cannot read property 'naturalWidth' of null` error.

The fix depends on your situation. For example, add a check `slideData.contextContainer !== null` or change the execution flow to call `slideData.dispose()` in a different place.